# Can I expand my /boot without upsetting the system?

Tags: 10.10, partitioning

This is the current state of my partition table. As can be seen, the boot is very small, and I can't upgrade the kernel, because the update-manager tells me there isnt enough space on /boot :( Which effectively means that I can't update my kernel. Can I change the size of my boot, without necessitating a reinstall of either of the installed system?

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5              12G  4.9G  6.2G  45% /
none                  2.0G  284K  2.0G   1% /dev
none                  2.0G  8.5M  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
none                  2.0G   92K  2.0G   1% /var/run
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /var/lock
/dev/sda3              42G   21G   22G  49% /media/Erste
/dev/sda2             5.1G  2.5G  2.7G  48% /media/Swap
/dev/sda1              30G   25G  4.9G  84% /media/Windows7
/dev/sda9              47G   28G   20G  60% /media/Zweite
/dev/sda6              11G  7.6G  2.0G  80% /home
/dev/sda8              49M   31M   16M  66% /boot
```

[This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/603724/) is the output of

`sudo fdisk -lu`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You posted the output of `df`, which is not a listing of your partition table.  For that you need to post the output of `fdisk -lu`.  The question is, what follows your `/boot` partition on the disk?  If it is not free space, or another partition that you can shrink a bit and move over, then no, you can not expand the `/boot` partition.

An alternative is to simply do away with the `/boot` partition.  First unmount the `/boot` partition and then remount it somewhere else, like `/mnt`.  Then `sudo cp -ax /mnt /boot` to copy all of the files over to your root partition.  Then remove the `/boot` partition entry from your `/etc/fstab`, and finally reinstall grub with `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`.

Comment: how will `cp -ax /mnt /boot` copy the files to the root partition?

Comment: @Kaustubh P: Because once /boot is no longer mounted as /boot, you can create a directory named boot in /.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can avoid this instead? It looks like your partition is big enough. Is it ok to remove old kernels? What is the kernel you are currently using? (`uname -r`) It might output something like 2.6.35-24-generic. And which kernels are installed? (`ls /boot | grep vmlinuz`), which might output something like

```
vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
vmlinuz-2.6.35-24-generic
```

In this example, you know you are using 2.6.35-24, so look for 2.6.35-22.

```
dpkg -l | grep 2.6.35-22
```

The output tells us which names to use for removing them

```
ii  linux-headers-2.6.35-22 2.6.35-22.35
    Header files related to Linux kernel version 2.6.35
ii  linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic 2.6.35-22.35
    Linux kernel headers for version 2.6.35 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic 2.6.35-22.35
    Linux kernel image for version 2.6.35 on x86/x86_64
```

Now we can

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-2.6.35-22 linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic
```

to make room for the new kernel to be installed.

Comment: Mind to **not** remove the current kernel by accident. Take double extra care on what you do. You might better control this and avoid typing errors by using a GUI like Synaptic.

Comment: `uname -r` and `ls /boot | grep vmlinuz` give the same kernel, which means there is only one installed!

Comment: psusi has a great suggestion