# Can I move the contents of the boot partition to the root drive?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

So the updater told me my /boot partition is out of space.

I came here from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/20932/282780), which recommended (if you can't expand it directly) to just move the contents of the boot partition to the primary partition and installing grub on it.

This was for 10.10, and it sounds rather risky to me. So is that still safe to do on 14.04 LTS?

This is not the same as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3402/how-to-move-boot-and-root-partitions-to-another-drive), whose hard drive is about to die. The answer does not mention moving contents of /boot.

Comment: Everything is risky if you don't have backups, if you do, nothing is.

Comment: Of course I have backups, what I mean with "risky" is that it has a chance of destroying (necessary) data, even if you have some sort of insurance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your boot partition is out of space it is most likely because there are too many old kernel images.

You can safely uninstall old kernels that you don't need/use anymore.
You can find the kernel version you are using with:

```
uname -a
```

To find all the installed kernels, instead:

```
dpkg -l 'linux-image*'|grep 'ii'
```

Comment: Easier yet, do `sudo apt-get autoremove`. That will usually remove all but two or three kernels.

Comment: Did that, cleaned up at least 50MB. Thanks! Also, can you do the same for the kernel config files, the "abi" files (of which I don't know what they are), and the initrd images?

Comment: Uninstalling the linux-image-* packages with `apt-get remove` should take care of removing all the files you mentined. I would follow @RodSmith's advice and just run `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: I did that, but it didn't remove any old kernels. I'll use the apt-get method.
Edit: That actually cleaned up almost 1 GB, which is indeed a lot better than 50 MB. Thanks!